# Implementing Azure Single sign-on run on google app engine project

Tags: java, azure, google-app-engine

I have made a project which uses adal (azure active directory authentication library) for single sign-on and is successfully implemented using this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-java

But now I am trying to run it on google app engine as i have to then integrate it to my google app engine project but after struggling (adding jars , resolving issues with jars) i got my code error free but now when running my project it is giving :

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") on line

Future future = context
                    .acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authCode, new URI(
                            currentUri), credential, null);

```
AuthenticationContext context = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenant + "/", true,
                    service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context
                    .acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authCode, new URI(
                            currentUri), credential, null);
            result = future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        }
```

And not getting what causing it. 
So if someone has idea on this please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. You could try to added the following line to the java.policy file:

> permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThreadGroup";

2. You could try to update version of database Driver.

In addition , you could refer to threads as below: 1.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wro4j/oYYc1XqZhbo
2.https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/47 which is same as your issue.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @yash Any progress now?